# c# Database error

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-express

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\HashTags.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

con.Open();
String queryStr = "SELECT name FROM ttable WHERE name LIKE '*%'";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(queryStr, con);
SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();

while (sdr.Read())
{
    this.trendingBx.Text = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString();
}

sdr.Close();
```

Could anyone tell me why I get this error:

> A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the database is not already attached?  If it is you should use:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=your database name;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HashTags;Integrated Security=sspi");

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share" you have already checked & the `.mdf` does exist at the location, I think you need not have the quotes in the connection string:

```
AttachDbFilename='C:\HashTags.mdf'
```

should be:

```
AttachDbFilename=C:\HashTags.mdf (no single quotes)
```

and this should work IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Integrated Security=SSPI
```

**not**

```
Integrated Security=True
```

in your connection string.